# Next value of primary key in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, primary-key

Advise me on how to get the next value of the primary key of an inserting row and use the value.
I am trying to create a table that stores thee paths.

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
  id serial primary key,
  path integer[] not null,
  content varchar(200) not null
);

insert into meters_location (content, path)
  values ('content_1', '{I need to put here the id of the inserted row}');
```

When I insert the row into the table the id generated value should be put as a path automatically, so if id = 1 then path = {1}.

it should be like:

```
id | path    | content       
-------------------------
1  | {1}     | content_1
```

Comment: This is not clear. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. But when clear this we can clearly expect this to be a faq. Before considering posting please read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts.

Comment: Ask 1 question per question. Ask a new question in a new post. Also please don't edit a question in a way that invalidates reasonable answers. I have rolled back your addition of a second question. If you have a question about clarifying an answer, put a comment on the answer.

Comment: Why are you storing the complete path and not just the ID of the parent? That will be a lot easier to deal with

Answer (score 0):

Use the `RETURNING` clause.

```
INSERT INTO meters_location (content, path) VALUES ('content_1', '{}') RETURNING id;
```

You can get any column's value from the affected table this way.

Edit:

If you just want to update an array column with the value of another column, you will need to use a trigger.  For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION update_ml_path() RETURNS trigger
AS $body$
BEGIN
  IF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
    NEW.path = ARRAY[NEW.id];
  END IF;

  RETURN NEW;
END;
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER set_ml_path BEFORE INSERT ON meters_location
  FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE FUNCTION update_ml_path();

postgres=# INSERT INTO meters_location (content, path) VALUES ('content_1', '{}');
INSERT 0 1

postgres=# SELECT * FROM meters_location;

 id | path |  content  
----+------+-----------
  1 | {1}  | content_1
(1 row)
```

If it's another table you need to update, you will need to adjust the trigger and function accordingly.

Comment: Thank you.
But I need to put the id as a value.
Insert into meters_location (content, path) values ('content_1', '{[I need to put here the value of its row id]}');

Comment: @RostislavKravchenko Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Comment: @RostislavKravchenko I've updated my answer with an example of a trigger.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lastval()` for that:

```
insert into meters_location (content, path)
values ('content_1', array[lastval()]);
```

This only works for single row inserts though.

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1f3ec56bb0d134bfc6238f9833279ea7)